# how do i send an xml string to a Socket Connection

Tags: java, xml, sockets, jaxb

i have a multi complex xml string and i want to send it over a TCP/IP Socket connection but i dont seem to know if string written or not,when i telnet to the server and send the request i get a response correctly, but i want to implement a socket class to send request and jaxb to parse my object classes to xml. below is the code

```
  Estel es = new Estel();
  Header hd = new Header();
  Request rq = new Request();
  hd.setRequestType("TOPUP");
  es.setHeader(hd);
  es.setRequest(rq);
  rq.setAgentCode("8033818446");
  rq.setPin("44B7A065BC937DE9406EABD6AB162AD4");
  rq.setDestination("08033818446");
  rq.setAgentTransId("20130618211503000021");
  rq.setVendorCode("CHIT");
  rq.setAmount(100);
  rq.setProductCode("MTNTOP");
  rq.setClientType("pc");
  rq.setComments("testing e top up");


 //JAXB mashalls the object to xml form 
 JAXBContext jaxb  = JAXBContext.newInstance(Estel.class);
 Marshaller msh = jaxb.createMarshaller();
 msh.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
  StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
 msh.marshal(es, str);


  //what the marshalled string looks like 
  /*<estel><header><requesttype>TOPUP</requesttype></header><request>  
  <agentcode>8033818446</agentcode><pin>44B7A065BC937DE9406EABD6AB162AD4</pin> 
  <destination>08033818446</destination>
  <agenttransid>20130618211503000021</agenttransid><vendorcode>CHIT</vendorcode>
  <amount>100</amount><productcode>MTNTOP</productcode><comments>Powered by ReadyCash Mobile Money</comments><clienttype>PC</clienttype></request>
  </estel> */


Socket soc = new Socket("41.206.23.21",7101);

OutputStream os =    soc.getOutputStream(); 
os.write(str.toString().getBytes());
os.flush();

soc.shutdownOutput();


 //Read input stream and unmarshall to object

    InputStream input = soc.getInputStream();

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxb.createUnmarshaller();

 System.out.print("\n--------passing---------"); 


Estel estel = (Estel)unmarshaller.unmarshal(input);
System.out.print("\n--------reading---------"); 
System.out.print("\nheader is "+estel.getHeader().getResponseType());
System.out.print("\ncode is"+estel.getResponse().getAgentCode());

os.close();
input.close();
soc.close();
```

I dont know if im doing the write thing, when i send this , i get invalid request in the xml body meaning i didnt send the right format,what is the proper way to send an xml marshalled in JAXB to a Socket server.

Comment: Can you try with this line commented out: msh.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

Comment: the line actually is to remove the UTF-8 charset because the server expects the xml request without utf-8